# Актер - профессия или представитель мужского рода?

Tags: значение-слов, род

Прочитал в статье такую фразу:

> «Фаворитка» — редчайший для «Оскара» фильм, где у женщин больше реплик,
>   чем у мужчин, — получила всего одну награду. Актерскую, естественно. 
>   Оливия Колман отмечена за роль королевы Анны («Оскар» прочили Гленн
>   Клоуз за «Жену», но она осталась с семью номинациями без побед — это
>   рекорд для актеров).

Вопрос в том, правильно ли в таком случае говорить "*для актеров*", имея ввиду всех представителей профессии, в том числе и женщин или говорить"для актрис" имея ввиду только женщин актеров?

Answer (score 1):

Это не менее правильно, чем называть организацию "гильдией актёров". В Гильдии актёров кино России почти половина членов правления - женщины (во многих других контекстах это "актрисы"). Обобщающее наименование охватывает *всех* представителей профессии, ко всем актёрам (безотносительно их пола или грамматического рода при конкретизации) относится и упомянутый "рекорд".